# Cloning a repo from my home directory

Tags: git, unix, permissions, git-clone

I recently git-ified a web project. [Following this guide](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/), I set up a bare repo in my home directory `/home/mt33` that acts as the hub for the clone sitting in `www/`. Then I cloned the bare repo (no working tree) to my local machine, make my changes, commit, and `push origin master` them to the server. The post-update script on the bare repo then takes care to `cd` to the `www/` clone, and pull all changes. This all works great.

I want to add a second developer, but he is unable to clone from the bare repo sitting in my home directory. So I asked the sysadmin to add group-read, group-write and group-execute permissions to my home directory and add the second dev to my group. Consequently, he confirmed that he can SSH to the server and `cd` into home directory, as well as see the contents of the `repo.git` directory. Here's what he sees:

`drwxrwxr-x 7 mt33 mt33 4096 2012-03-07 19:10 repo.git`

When he tries to clone using

`git clone theseconddev@theserver:/home/mt33/repo.git my_directory` he gets the error

`fatal: '/home/mt33/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

At this point I'm not sure what to do... Is the bare repo in my home directory a problem? Any pointers appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to also add those permissions for the files *within* `/home/mt33/repo.git`.

```
chmod -R g+rwx /home/mt33/repo.git
```

(Also make sure to set `sharedRepository=true` inside the `config` file to properly preserve the permissions in the future.)

Comment: Fantastic. Hadn't thought of that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try having your second developer clone from the www location.  If that works (don't let him/her push :-), then there are alternate workflows that you could use (as a work-around to your actual problem) and you might learn something about or ssh/git setup.